# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint The conflict occurred in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to add a player in the table that doesn't have a team and I'm getting the following exception :

> INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint The
>   conflict occurred in database.

This is my playerModel, I have foreign key id_team that is nullable and yet when I am trying to add a player I get this error.

```
public class PlayerModel
{
    public int id_player { get; set; }
    public string player_surname { get; set; }
    public string player_firstname { get; set; }
    public int player_skill { get; set; }
    public int? id_team { get; set; }
    public string name_team { get; set; }
    public int player_value { get; set; }
}
```

I put a breakpoint and when is trying to save in database is getting exception

```
public bool CreateNewPlayer(PlayerModel newPlayer)
{
    if (newPlayer == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (newPlayer.player_surname==null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (newPlayer.player_firstname==null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var newDBPlayer = mappingService.MapPlayerFromForm(newPlayer);
    dbContext.players.Add(newDBPlayer);

    try
    {
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

here I mapped the player model for database model

```
public players MapPlayerFromForm(PlayerModel formPlayer)
{
    var toRet = new players
    {
        player_firstname=formPlayer.player_firstname,
        player_surname=formPlayer.player_surname,
        player_skill=formPlayer.player_skill,
        id_team=formPlayer.id_team,
        player_value=formPlayer.player_value

    };
    return toRet;
}
```

I'm using jquery to add player into database. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What does the db schema look like and the relationship?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xBwWlgd.png this is my db schema with only those two tables and relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MapPlayerFromForm`, check the value of `formPlayer.id_team` and if it's 0, then set the value to `NULL`.  Also, set the `id_team` property in `players` to a `nullable int`, or it will take a default value of 0.

```
public class players //consider calling this Player
{
  public int? id_team {get;set;}
}
```

In the method...

```
id_team=formPlayer.id_team == 0 ? null : formPlayer.id_team,
```

See [`? Operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) on msdn.